# Magento 2: How to remove Category using category id by Mysql script

Tags: database, category, magento-2.1.10

I want to remove category using MySql Script

So I can delete the category using category ID completely from magento 2 as we did in admin area category section.

Answer (score 2):

Use below query to delete category by id from mysql

```
delete from catalog_category_entity where entity_id= category_id;
```

Comment: Are you sure it delete the category completely from all related tables in database?

Comment: yes you can check in local it will delete all related data also

Comment: yes i did check it its deleting all related data also from catalog_category_entity_int table also

Comment: This works, but obviously does not delete anything from any other table and you will be left with redundant data in other tables. That's not so bad, unless you're really anal about it. I however, am not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove specific category then instead of SQL you can also do it via Root File.

> Just create category-delete.php file on the root folder

See below example:

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('app/bootstrap.php');

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();    
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');    

$rootCat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
$cat_info = $rootCat->load(1832); //1832 is the category ID
$cat_info->delete();
echo '<pre>';print_r($cat_info->getData());die('died');
```

Let me know the above example is helpful or not?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for Mysql query to delete the category in magento 2